# edited PHP code does not reflect to webpage

Tags: php, xampp, html, edit

I was given backup files of a website and they asked me to add a feature in their website. The website runs just fine on my local computer (We are both using **XAMPP**) but when I edit the **PHP** code on my local computer, It doesn't reflect on the webpage. Although when I was connected to another network (in my home) the webpage showed the changes that I made. But i need to work on the webpage using their network. What can i do?

**Notes:** I can do edits using their computer but they wont allow me to make changes there. All files including DB are the working, I just cant edit.

Comment: Did you upload the updated files to their network/server/etc?

Comment: No, I haven't. It's only because i haven't finished it yet and i have to work on it when im connected to their network

Comment: That's the answer then. You didn't upload it to their server so how do you expect your changes to reflect there?

Comment: that makes sense. But why is it that my edited codes reflect on the webpage when im connected to my own network at home and not with theirs? is there some kind of settings i need to change?

Comment: Browser cache? ... you may need to clear this between edits, OR run in the "incognito" or "private" mode depending upon the browser.

Comment: Are you sure you are editing the right file in right folder (in your public folder) of your computer. May be you are editing the downloaded file in your downloads folder.